# Android Activity / FragmentActivity Project Structure and inheritance

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I am quite new to Android development. In my project I have a list view and a map view which are pretty much different representations of the same data, and I my first thought in approaching it was to extend the `Activity` class and have both of these extending that.

`NearbyPlacesActivity extends Activity`

`PlacesListActivity extends NearbyPlacesActivity`

`PlacesMapActivity extends NearbyPlacesActivity`

However, maps seem to need to be developed in a class extending `FragmentActivity`, so my idea falls over.

What approach could I take to developing this without having to copy & paste > half the code in each class?

Comment: You already have the support lib imported, why don't use `FragmentActivity` as your base class for `NearbyPlacesActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentActivity` extends `Activity`, it is from v4 and can use the supported-based fragment.
You can change `NearbyPlacesActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.